# Whitespaces in arguments in aux file

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I am using document template provided here: http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/conf-1.7b.html.
My MWI is the `tex` file supplied with the template itself. All I have done is to change author name, conference number etc. and rename `tex` and `bib` files(the new file names do not contain spaces) and include a few packages such as `fontenc`, `babel`. You can find the full changes in the diff link below.
However when I compile with MikTeX, the resulting `aux` file contains entries like `\citation{2.5pt plus 1.49998pt minus 0.59998pt}` and thus it generates empty `bbl` file and no bibliography. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT 1**
I think this goes without saying but I changed `\bibliography` command to

```
\bibliography{References}
```

after renaming the `bib` file to `References.bib`. My `tex` file name is `Report.tex`

**EDIT 2**
The MWI is difficult to cut down because I don't know which section is causing a problem. You can take a look at this diff to see what changes I have done to `tex` file that came with template: http://www.diffchecker.com/bvge2l6m. The original `tex` file compiles fine with bibliography.

Comment: Can you give some examples of your `\cite` commands?

Comment: I have not changed any `\cite` commands in the tex file that came with template except for 1 change I tried: I tried eliminating spaces as `\cite{abc, def}` to `\cite{abc,def}` with no effect.

Comment: Btw, would newline character play a role here(LF, CRLF)? I am kinda jumping between MikTeX(uses LF) and Notepad++(uses CRLF) on Windows.

Comment: No, the newline character shouldn't be a concern

Comment: what does your .log file look like. Or preferably try to cut down to a minimal example that you can post here that does the same thing)

Comment: `\citation` is written when a `\cite` command appears in the `.tex` file. Without any other change than what you mention I'd think it's unlikely to obtain a behavior as you describe.

Comment: I don't know why but `babel` package seems to create some problem. Removing that package generates the bibliography. Any idea why?

Comment: well I was going to suggest babel but didn't when I saw you had `[english]` as that doesn't do so much compared to other languages ( `,` made into a babel active shorthand migh tmess things up) but now you know what it is you should be able to make a small example that you can post here for people to debug. _All_ questions should have an inline example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimal example producing the wrong behavior is

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{xyz,xxx}
\end{document}
```

with which the `.aux` file show

```
\citation{0.0pt}
```

The erroneous behavior is due to the fact that `asme2e.cls` defines `\@citex` in a way that pleases it, while `babel` redefines the macro in an incompatible way.

The conclusion is that the class is not compatible with `babel`, although it should be. A possible workaround is to nullify `babel`'s redefinition of `\@citex`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}

\makeatletter
\let\asme@citex\@citex % save amse2e definition of \@citex
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\makeatletter
\let\@citex\asme@citex % restore
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{xyz,xxx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's seems to explain the incompatibility.

Comment: Shouldn't your ME include `babel` if `babel` is required to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @cfr Yes; I removed too much!